# Switching focus to the next input field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

In my react application, there is a part with entering the verification code. It looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tw8I.png)

I want the focus to automatically switch to the next digit input field when entering the next digit. Right now I'm using DOM manipulation, but I want to find a more powerful solution.

my code right now:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-shadow-vqojs2?file=/src/App.js

I saw options for solving problems using Ref. But adding 5 refs is also not very good, in my humble opinion. Please advise something

Comment: Why do you think having 5 refs is not good?  That's exactly how I would go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ref` is the solution here

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-burnell-g8uwg6?file=/src/App.js)

Declare ref:

```
const itemsRef = useRef([]);
```

Add ref of inputs

```
<input
  ref={(ref) => itemsRef.current.push(ref)}
  name={`code-${index}`}
  key={index}
  style={{ width: "20px", height: "20px" }}
  onChange={(event) => codeChangeHandler(event)}
  maxLength={1}
/>
```

Focus next ref:

```
itemsRef.current[fieldIntIndex + 1].focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, if the `inputs` are siblings, you can easily check if there are `nextElementSibling` for the current input, if **YES**, then focus on it, if **NOT** ( the last input in the list ), then blur

```
const codeChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const element = event.target;
    const nextSibling = element.nextElementSibling;
    nextSibling ? nextSibling.focus() : element.blur();
};
```

[This is a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-lake-21vufv)